# Why mbp keyboard light stays on while playing video in fullscreen?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I noticed macbook pro keyboard light stays on while playing video in fullscreen, on youtube and vlc. Wouldn't be better if apple auto turn it off (since I'm not using keyboard while watching movies)?

I'm using latest macOS on mbp 15 retina.

Keyboard light works normally in other situations, if I stop typing for a while it goes off.

Comment: Does it stays on only when playing full screen video?

Comment: Question edited to address your comment.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube is a web-based video platform and VLC is a 3rd party program. These are not Apple-made applications and so may not be built specifically for the hardware you are using.

You can control the MacBook Pro keyboard lighting on your F5 and F6 keys for these 3rd party applications.

Comment: This is partly incorrect.  Youtube and other HTML5 videos use the Quicktime (Apple made) plugin to play videos (at least in Safari).  They are just styled using CSS.

Comment: @Josh - QuickTime has been deprecated and you do not need it to play HTML5 video.  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205081

Comment: @Allan that maybe correct but the article only talks about old version of QuickTime.

Comment: Yes (you referenced the QuickTime plugin).  It's not used for HTML5 video whatsoever.